# gnome-shell, gnome 3, unity, cinnamon, mate confusion

Tags: 12.04, gnome, cinnamon, mate

I am thinking about adding something besides unity into my ubuntu 12.04.

My questions are this: 
-If I add cinnamon, mate, gnome2/3, could I still call it it Ubuntu, or would it be Mint?
-Why not just add Mint instead of cinnamon, or mate, into Ubuntu?
-Or is Mint just those at the core, and not the other way around?
-I had terrible battery drain using Mint. Something was wrong with the kernel with my laptop type. If I add cinnamon, would I get that battery drain again?
-And lastly, would I be able to get that awesome HUD if I add the other things?

I realize these questions are a bit confusing, or at least they are for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -If I add cinnamon, mate, gnome2/3, could I still call it it Ubuntu, or would it be Mint?

It is still Ubuntu.

> Why not just add Mint instead of cinnamon, or mate, into Ubuntu? Or is Mint just those at the core, and not the other way around?

I did not understand what you mean, Mint as Ubuntu is a community of users and developers, both with goals that may or may not convey same thing.

> -I had terrible battery drain using Mint. Something was wrong with the kernel with my laptop type. If I add cinnamon, would I get that battery drain again?

Cinnamon is a Desktop Environment and it's just that it is not an Operating System. . Cinnamon might have been "heavier" in terms of resource using so it "*may* have caused your battery to drain faster.

> -And lastly, would I be able to get that awesome HUD if I add the other things?

No, HUD is intended to be used with Unity *only*.